# No USB storage mode for Asus MeMo Pad 7 to do Android development

Tags: usb

I intend to develop with an Asus MeMo Pad 7, but I can't set it to detect as a normal USB storage device.

In the Storage menu I have 4 options:

1. MTP - to transfer images
2. PTP - to transfer images
3. USB charge mode -no USB, just charging
4. CD mode - a CD image

I enabled Developer mode and set USB debug. I still can't see the tablet as an USB Storage.

What mode should I use for Android development?

Comment: Why do you need mass storage mode for development? That's what USB debugging mode is for. The two are not related, and most newer devices don't support UMS anymore (see, e.g. [How can I use my Galaxy Nexus as an external USB storage drive?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26288))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based my opinion on the phones I've used so far, but it seems, new devices don't care about USB mode, they just work. I used MTP and my Android IDE recognized the device. It made my day.